# Header is not fixed

Tags: css

hello everyone i am designing a web page. i which i want a fixed header.

For this i set `position: fixed;`. but when i add a anther `<div>` in the web page and set some top margin for it then margin of header is also changed here is my CSS for header

```
#header {
  width:100%;
  height:35%;
  color:#303030;
  postion:fixed;
}
```

and the CSS for the div below header is this

```
#content {
  width:250px;
  height:350px;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-top:75px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#303030;
  border-width:1px;
}
```

my html

```
<div id="header">
Predufu
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

*I add little part of my html in this question*

now in `#content` i set `margin-top: 75px;` but with this the margin of header is also changed why it is happened please tell me i need a fixed header in my web page

Comment: please show your HTML too

Comment: at least you have one error.. postion should be position

Comment: you dont have coordinates it's fixed to. `top: 0px; left:0px;`

Comment: @DanielStutz sorry for the mistake i write this css right now. so its by mistake sorry

Comment: @Mark ok i am adding html too please check it

Comment: @Azad no thing Azad.. errors are normal

Comment: @DanielStutz ok sir so now please tell me where i am wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to add its top position to header. Also your spelt position wrong.

try this:

```
#header {
  width:100%;
  height:35%;
  color:#303030;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

## [JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZLrT/)

Comment: How do you know it is not already shown as `block` (if it is a `div` for example)?

Comment: To make sure it is displayed as a block display: block; should be there. And if it is already, then it doesn't affect it.

Comment: It does not need a unit but it is good practice to have one as you can use different measurement units. Is the downvote necessary was my answer not correct?

Comment: I find it so non-constructive when now 2 people downvote an answer that is in fact correct.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of the CSS attributes and it worked. First I tried with position: absolute, but it also works with position: fixed.

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    color:#303030;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
    width:250px;
    height:350px;
    border: 1px solid 303030;
}
```

See here with position : fixed --> http://jsfiddle.net/NicHope/n32Mu/
Is it this you are looking for ?